# Find max element in matrix

Tags: c, matrix, rows

I need some help with C programming.
I need to to find matrix D=(A+B)*C, then find largest element in this matrix and create a new one, without row and column where this element is placed.
So, I found this matrix, but i do not how to find max element and how to cut the matrix. I hope someone can help me with that.

file.txt

```
4

1 0 -10 1
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 1
3 4 6 7

1 1 0 8 
0 1 -10 3
0 1 1 1
1 5 8 5

11 -19 0 8 
-10 1 10 3
0 10 12 1
1 2 -32 4
```

And code itself.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
   {
   int n,i,j,k=0;
   int t=0;
   int m[300],a[10][10],b[10][10],c[10][10];
   int d1[10][10],d[10][10];
   FILE *f;
   f=fopen("file.txt","r");
   if(f!=NULL)
   {
    fscanf(f,"%d",&n);
    for(i=0; i<(n-1)*n*n;i++)
     fscanf(f,"%d",&m[i]);
   }

   for(i=0; i<n;i++)
    for(j=0; j<n;j++)
    {
     a[i][j]=m[k]; //Matrix A
     k++;
    }

   for(i=0; i<n;i++)
    for(j=0; j<n;j++)
    {
     b[i][j]=m[k]; //Matrix b
     k++;
    }
   for(i=0; i<n;i++)
    for(j=0; j<n;j++)
    {
     c[i][j]=m[k]; //Matrix C
     k++;
    }
   printf("A+B=\n\n");
   for(i=0; i<n;i++)
   {
    for(j=0; j<n;j++)
    {
     d1[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j]; //Matrix (A+B)
     printf("%d ",d1[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
   }

   printf("\nD=(A+B)*C\n\n");
   for(i=0; i<n;i++)
   {
    for(j=0; j<n;j++)
    {
     d[i][j]=0;

     for(t=0; t<n;t++)
      d[i][j]=d[i][j]+d1[i][t]*c[t][j]; //Matrix D
     printf("%d ",d[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
   }

         fclose(f);
  }
```

Output:

```
A+B=
2 1 -10 9
0 2 -10 4 
1 1 2 2
4 9 14 12

D=(A+B)*C
21 -119 -398 45 
-16 -90 -228 12
3 6 -30 21 
-34 97 -126 121
```

Comment: No, you can, I meant if max element is in 3-rd row and 2-nd column, then new matrix should be without this row and column.

Comment: By cutting the matrix it is easier just to copy this matrix to a new one skipping the elements of the row and column you do not want.

Comment: And how to do if there is more than one element of the maximum value?

Comment: BLUEPIXY, oops, you are right, I didn't really notice that.
Changed input, added output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *max_cut(int size, int mat[size][size], int n){
    //size : real size, n : used size
    int new_n = n - 1;//n > 1
    int (*result)[new_n] = malloc(new_n*sizeof(*result));
    int nr, nc;
    int r, c, max_r=0, max_c=0;
    for(r=0; r<n ;++r){
        for(c=0; c<n; ++c){
            if(mat[r][c] > mat[max_r][max_c]){//It is not updated when there is same value.
                max_r = r;
                max_c = c;
            }
        }
    }
    for(nr=r=0; r<n; ++r){
        if(max_r == r)
            continue;//skip
        for(nc=c=0; c<n; ++c){
            if(max_c == c)
                continue;//skip
            result[nr][nc++] = mat[r][c];
        }
        ++nr;
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void){
    int mat[10][10] = {
        { 21,-119,-398, 45},
        {-16, -90,-228, 12},
        {  3,   6, -31, 21},
        {-34,  97,-126,121}
    };
    int n = 4;
    int (*result)[n-1] = max_cut(10, mat, n);
    int r, c;
    n -= 1;
    for(r=0; r<n; ++r){
        for(c=0; c<n; ++c)
            printf("%5d", result[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(result);

    return 0;
}
```